# Finding all isolated buffer points using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, pgadmin-4

I am doing a project where I find the banks in Ireland using PostGIS and pgAdmin
[image: I have marked the points that I want to find]

I want to run a query that finds all the buffer spaces that do not intersect with any nearby buffers. I am using St_intersect after applying the buffer but that does not seem to work.

How do I find the isolated points in the picture above?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Please add the SQL you are using and a description of what isn't working

Comment: How many buffers are there?

Comment: For proximity searches better use `ST_DWithin`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ST_ClusterDBSCAN](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html):

```
with cte as (
select id, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, eps := 0, minpoints := 2) over () AS cluster_id, geom
from public.buffers100k)
select id, geom from cte where cluster_id is null
```

< 1 s. for 100 000 buffers:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to test the intersection on itself using a `left join`. Then you can do a `group by` using the geometry and finally set a filter only on those that have a `count(1)` equal to one. According to your data you need to replace the name of the initial points table in the `with` clause and you need to rename all occurrences of the geometry column.

```sql
with sub as(
    select
        *,
        st_buffer(geometry, 15000) as geometry
    from 
        points
) 
select
    *
from sub a
left join sub b
on st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
group by a.geometry
having count(1) = 1
```

**Update**
If you have more than the geometry column this will work (we need to rejoin with the first sub-query). But maybe there is a faster solution.

```sql
with sub as(
    select
        st_buffer(geometry, 15000) as geometry
    from 
        points
)
select
    *
from (
    select 
        *
    from (
        select
            a.geometry,
            count(1) as count
        from sub a
        left join sub b
        on st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
        group by a.geometry
    ) sub2
    where sub2.count = 1
) sub3
left join sub
on st_equals(sub.geometry, sub3.geometry)
```

[image]

Comment: This can be restated as "Find polygons which are not polygons which intersect another one", which can be solved by using the **anti-join** pattern.  Use a `NOT EXISTS` query as described [here](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/rise-of-the-anti-join).